# Continue the event after preventDefault() JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to prevent the default bahavior of reloading the page after submitting a form, to show an information and after a second or so, continue with that event(submit) that provokes the refresh.

I've done this

**HTML:**

```
    <form id="uploadForm" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data onsubmit="showConfirmationModal(event)">
      <span id="confirmationModal" class="confirmModal"></span>
      <input type=file name=file>
      <input id="uploadButton" class="primaryButton" type=submit class="primaryButton" value=Enviar>
    </form>
```

**JS:**

```
const showConfirmationModal = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const confirmation = document.getElementById('confirmationModal')
  confirmation.innerText = " Uploading File ... ";
  confirmation.style.display = 'inline';
  setTimeout(() =>{
    document.getElementById("uploadForm").submit();
  },1000)
}
```

But the document that it's being loaded is not being sended.

Any idea?

Thank you!

*(I have been looking for some info but most of people uses JQuery to solve the problem and i'ts something that I don't want to do, I'd like to use only JS)*

Comment: Your submit is going to hit your `preventDefault()` again, just set a flag that says you have submitted, and then exit the function.

Comment: So, presumably to deal with impatient users(?), you are trying to show this confirmation message that _pretends_ the file was already uploading, but in reality it slows down the process by adding an additional, unnecessary second of wait time?

Comment: @CBroe  Maybe requires what's uploaded for the next page, but yeah, using a timeout seems a bit hacky.. A Promise when the file has been uploaded would be better.  Why wait a second, when the file might take 100ms, or even worse with a network glitch, could take longer than a second..

Comment: @Keith Nope, when submitting is done via the [submit method of the form](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#form-submission-algorithm), the native form validation and submit handlers are ignored.

Comment: @CBroe The idea behind this was to show to the user some information before the upload itself it's done (Since, submitting only refresh the page from the user side whithout leaving any info). This was done because I don't have any backend response or something that let me know if the file was upload correctly. Ofc if you want to really use this code it should be done in a different way

Comment: @Keith Yep, Teemu is right, I tried it because I thought that it would end up being an infinite loop but it worked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change the

```
type=submit
```

to

```
type=button
```

In this case (as @mousetail mentioned) of course you have to move the event handler to the click event.

If you wanna stick with submit, try

```
return false
```

At the end of the handler.

```
function mySubmit(e) { 
  e.preventDefault(); 
  try {
   someBug();
  } catch (e) {
   throw new Error(e.message);
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but in this case you need to move the event handler to the button

Comment: Yep, added that one as well to avoid confusion, ty

Comment: @EndreSzabó What I've done is removing the event.preventDefault() and the parameter in the function and added a listener onclick="showConfirmationModal" in the button, so it doesn't submit until the modal show up one second

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code which show a feature of a modal show after the `submit` button is clicked and the form is processed only after the confirmation with the button shown on the modal

```js
let submitBtn = document.getElementById("uploadButton");
let modal = document.getElementById("modal");
let confirmBtn = document.getElementById("confirm");
let uploadForm = document.getElementById("uploadForm");
submitBtn.addEventListener('click', event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  modal.style.display = "flex";
});

confirmBtn.addEventListener('click', event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  uploadForm.submit();
});
```

```css
#modal{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}

#modal .modal-content {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<form id="uploadForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <span id="confirmationModal" class="confirmModal"></span>
      <input type=file name=file>
      <input id="uploadButton" class="primaryButton" type=submit class="primaryButton" value=Enviar>
</form>
<div id="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <button id="confirm">Confirm</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is a simple stuff like showing confirmation modal once you can play with mouseenter

```
$(document).on('mouseenter','.button',function(e) {
    //some stuff before click
});
```

for example

```
$(document).on('mouseenter','.button',function(e) {
    //if class not exist yet -> do ajax
    
    //after complete add class
    $(this).addClass('ajx-event-completed');
});

$(document).on('click','.button',function(e) {
    if($(this).hasClass('ajx-event-completed')){
        //do something else
    }
    else{
        e.preventDefault();
        //we are CLOSED today! See you next week
    }
    //do more
});
```